# ASP.net MVC Return File and Redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controller that returns csv file. I want to redirect to an action after this has displayed, i.e. return to the home view.
The controller logic is shown below:

```
public ActionResult DownloadCSV(string fileName)
{
    string csv;
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
    {
        csv = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
    return File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(csv), "text/csv", "Export.csv");
}
```

Comment: HTTP does not support that.

Comment: Hi,I should have meant that this action is called from another controller which creates the file, it is not called from a view

Comment: return  RedirectToAction("DownloadCSV", new { fileName = exportedCancelFile });

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short version is that you can't force a file download and redirect in the same action because of HTTP limitations. But you could force the download by opening the file-download action using `window.open`.

**Example:**

```
<a href="Action/RedirectPage" data-file="Action/DownloadCVS" class="file-download">Download File</a>

<script>
  $(function() {
      $('a.file-download').click(function() {
         window.open($(this).data('file'));
      }); 
  });
</script>
```

In this case I used HTML5 attributes, but you're not limited to do it in this way.