# Run script after file download

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In ASP.Net MVC application I have a button on the view and on click event it returns to the action which is

```
public void ExportToExcel()
    {  
        string startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Session["DateStart"]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        string endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Session["DateEnd"]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        int hierarchyID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["HierarchyID"]);

        DataBaseManager dbManager = new DataBaseManager();
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(dbManager.GetConnectionString());
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("RPT_GetEmpTimeBoardForPeriodAndHierarchyPosition", connection);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("StartDate", startDate));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("EndDate", endDate));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("HierarchyID", hierarchyID));
        command.CommandTimeout = 360;
        connection.Open();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        da.Fill(dt);

        GridView gv = new GridView();
        gv.DataSource = dt;
        gv.DataBind();

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        gv.RenderControl(htw);

        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename=TabelFor_{0}-{1}.xls",
                            Convert.ToDateTime(Session["DateStart"]).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"),
                            Convert.ToDateTime(Session["DateEnd"]).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")));

        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        Response.Charset = "";
        ViewBag.AlertMessage = "Download completed";

        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());           

        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
```

I can disable button when it's been clicked, but how can I enable it when file has already been downloaded.
Thank's in advance.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364096/asp-net-mvc-return-file-and-redirect

Comment: I think this is not what I want

Comment: @Iskuhi do you mean once download is complete you want to alert ?

Comment: No I want to disable button when user clicks, and enable it when user recieve response(file downlaoded) , I want to do it because file constructing in my case lasts about 1 minute, and I don't want user to click button several times

Comment: @Iskuhi please show the button event handler

Comment: Here it is ` $('#btnExportToExcel').on('click', function () {
        $('#imgLoading').css("display", "block");
        $(this).prop("disabled", true);       
        window.location.href = "/Home/Report";     
    });`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should trigger window load event so you can bind your handler to enable the button to it, just like that

```
$(document).load(function(){
   $('#buttonId').prop("disabled", false);
});
```

Please note I didn't had a chance to test it with your scenario and it might require you to make some tweaks before it actually works.

Hope it helps!