# How to redirect to homepage ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When the user clicks print/issue it produces a pdf file however; I would like the user to open the pdf file in a different tab as well as the current tab redirects to the home page; Because I already have a return; I'm not sure how to redirect to the homepage at the same time. This is what I have thus far

```
 <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="col-md-4">Item Number</th>
                        <th class="col-md-4">Item Description</th>
                        <th class="col-md-4">Expense Account</th>
                        <th class="col-md-2">Quantity Requested</th>
                        <th class="col-md-2">Quantity Issued</th>
                        <th class="col-md-1">UOM</th>
                        <th class="col-md-1">Item Price</th>

                    </tr>


                    @{
                        if (@Model.items.Count > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (var issueditem in @Model.items)
                            {
                                <tr>

                                    <td class="col-md-4">@issueditem.itemNumber</td>
                                    <td class="col-md-4">@issueditem.description</td>
                                    <td class="col-md-4">@issueditem.expense_account.getDescription</td>
                                    <td class="col-md-2">@issueditem.quantity.ToString()</td>
                                    <td class="col-md-2">@issueditem.quantityI.ToString()</td>
                                    <td class="col-md-1">@issueditem.selecteduomtext </td>
                                    <td class="col-md-1">@issueditem.price.ToString()</td>


                                    <td> @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = issueditem.lineNum }) </td>


                                </tr>
                            }

                        }


                    }



                </table>





                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" formaction="@Url.Action("ReceiptPrint")">Print/Issue</button>
```

Controller

```
 public ActionResult ReceiptPrint(Issue issue)
    {
        IssueDAO dbdata = new IssueDAO();
        dbdata.connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings

["TConnectionString"].ConnectionString;


        Item item = new Item();


        try
        {
            dbdata.createIssue(getIssue, item);//Creates the issue in the database
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogWrite logWriter = new LogWrite(ex.ToString());
            ViewBag.errorMessage = "Unable to complete the Issue. Please see Log file for more Information";
            return View("Index", getIssue);

        }
        DataSet ds = dbdata.GetReceipt(getIssue.requisitionNumber);



        LocalReport localreport = new LocalReport();
        localreport.ReportPath = Request.MapPath(Request.ApplicationPath) + @"Reports\Reciept.rdlc";
        localreport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("Receipt_Data", ds.Tables[0]));
        localreport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("Req_num", getIssue.requisitionNumber));

        string reporttype = "PDF";
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string fileNameExtension = "pdf";
        string deviceInfo = @"<DeviceInfo>              
                 <OutputFormat>PDF</OutputFormat>              
                 <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>              
                 <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>          
                 <MarginTop>0.25in</MarginTop>          
                 <MarginLeft>0.45in</MarginLeft>            
                 <MarginRight>0.45in</MarginRight>       
                 <MarginBottom>0.25in</MarginBottom></DeviceInfo>";
        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streams;
        byte[] renderedBytes;
        renderedBytes = localreport.Render(
         reporttype, deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out fileNameExtension,
         out streams, out warnings);


        var doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
        var reader = new PdfReader(renderedBytes);
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/Receipt" +
             Convert.ToString(Session["CurrentUserName"]) + ".pdf"), FileMode.Create))
        {
            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fs);
            string Printer = "Xerox Phaser 3635MFP PCL6";
            // This is the script for automatically printing the pdf in acrobat viewer
            stamper.JavaScript = "var pp = getPrintParams();pp.interactive =pp.constants.interactionLevel.automatic; pp.printerName = " +
                           Printer + ";print(pp);\r";
            stamper.Close();
        }
        reader.Close();
        FileStream fss = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/Receipt.pdf"), FileMode.Open);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[fss.Length];
        fss.Read(bytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fss.Length));
        fss.Close();
        System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~/Receipt.pdf"));
        return File(bytes, "application/pdf");


    }
```

Comment: In client server model there is a request and a response for that request, can't reply twice to the same request (with a file and a page). Need to use Javascript in order to make another request.

Comment: can show me with using javascript

Comment: @derloopkat; is it possible to assist me

Comment: I have published a solution that should work. However it can be improved by using Ajax instead.

Comment: Tested it in Chrome 62, FF 57, IE 11, all worked. Do you return as attachment as I mentioned in last step? If yes, then might be it takes long time for returning the PDF and redirection runs first. Try using Ajax instead and redirect in success function.

Comment: yes i added the last step; i'm not familiar with using ajax

Comment: without ajax, another solution is redirecting to home and pass a parameter to tell that page download is due, then add a script for changing location and since file is downloaded as attachment, this will do the trick

Comment: also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364096/asp-net-mvc-return-file-and-redirect

Comment: ok thanks for your help appreciate it