# IActionResult return both file and view from Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to return both file for download and update a view from IActionResult?

If not, is there a workaround? (JavaScript or AJAX)

I am hoping to refresh a view after the file download.

**Code:**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ProcessFile(ViewModel model, List<IFormFile> files)
{
    var uploadedfileName = UploadFile(files);
    try
    {
        if (uploadedfileName != null)
        {
            // Generate a report for download
            var fileInfo = GenerateReports(model.Host, uploadedfileName);

            // Prompt Download File
            var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
            var downloadData = webClient.DownloadData(fileInfo.ToString());
            var content = new System.IO.MemoryStream(downloadData);
            var contentType = "APPLICATION/octet-stream";
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileInfo.ToString());
            return File(content, contentType, fileName);                    
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Please select the file";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Log Error
    }
    finally
    {
        // Delete the file after the report is generated
        System.IO.File.Delete(uploadedfileName);
    }
    return View("Index");
}
```

Comment: how are you requesting it? ajax would be the way to go.

Comment: See if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17364640/2263507) help you.