# Redirect to action after end response don't work vb.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, model-view-controller, web-applications, httpresponse

Hello i have nomes issues when i export data to xls file through a response 
the response works fine i got my xls file but the page doesn't redirect to Index page
here is my Action code

```
Function excel() As ActionResult
        Dim lst_ids As List(Of String) = TempData("listIds")
        Dim sheet As New DataTable
        Dim export_data As New DataBaseManager
        sheet = export_data.Export_toexcel(lst_ids)

        Dim grid As New GridView
        grid.DataSource = sheet
        grid.DataBind()

        Response.ClearContent()
        Response.Buffer = True
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=MyExcelFile.xls")
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel"

        Response.Charset = ""
        Dim sw As New StringWriter
        Dim htw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)

        grid.RenderControl(htw)

        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString())
        Response.Flush()
        Response.End()
        Return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home")


    End Function
```

The action stop in response.End() ! before execute RedirectToAction method

How can i execute response and return to action same time ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.net MVC Return File and Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364096/asp-net-mvc-return-file-and-redirect)

Comment: Of course because that's what `Response.End` does. Go through the link above to understand why you can't do what you're asking without spawning another `HTTP Request`

Comment: You cannot use `Response.Output.Write` together with `RedirectToAction` in the same controller action. It is necessary to redirect to download page first and provide a link to download the file.